# Where are characters stored for display?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unicode, terminal, ascii

Open a terminal. Type some stuff. Some characters appear on the screen. Where are the characters you see stored on disk? In what format are they stored?

I'm dreaming of a silly little project to teach my students about unicode and text encodings. I want to show that \x24 doesn't mean "$" - it's just printed that way because that's the way the computer is told to represent those bytes when you tell it that they are encoded utf8.

I don't want to handle this within my application with a map or anything, I want to know where in the depths of my ubuntu installation can I find a file that instructs the os/application/whatever to render the character 00100100 as $.

Does anyone know? I wonder if the solution is simple or really hairy.

Comment: Search for "Ubuntu fonts".

Comment: Thanks I suspected it was the fonts, but wasn't sure. I guess as an experiment I'm going to go into all my font directories on a VM and delete them all and then see what chaos ensues. Will report back soon.

Comment: Before you go: make a backup!

Comment: Also, here's a really interesting post http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14027/what-fonts-are-good-for-unicode-glyphs

Comment: I think if you are starting with a UTF-8 encoded Unicode codepoint, you'll have show the 21 bit codepoint value on your way to the TTF index. They'll come out ahead if you don't mention ASCII.

Comment: @ Tom I'm not quite sure what you mean. UTF-8 is a variable width encoding, so you don't always use the full 4 bytes. "$" is stored in a single byte, for example.

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Teacher's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different terminals use different font rendering mechanisms, and get their font data from different places in different formats.

VGA consoles will by default use a font stored in the VGA BIOS. New fonts can be loaded and written to VRAM from `/usr/share/consolefonts` or `/usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts` or similar with `setfont`. On disk they're stored in an ancient DOS [`.psf` format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_Screen_Font). Characters are not rendered by the OS, but by the VGA adapter itself.

FB consoles use bitmap fonts compiled into the kernel. They're declared in C files in the kernel tree like [lib/fonts/font_8x16.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/fonts/font_8x16.c) like this (squint a bit to see that the 1s form a dollar sign):

```
/* 36 0x24 '$' */
0x18, /* 00011000 */
0x18, /* 00011000 */
0x7c, /* 01111100 */
0xc6, /* 11000110 */
0xc2, /* 11000010 */
0xc0, /* 11000000 */
0x7c, /* 01111100 */
0x06, /* 00000110 */
0x06, /* 00000110 */
0x86, /* 10000110 */
0xc6, /* 11000110 */
0x7c, /* 01111100 */
0x18, /* 00011000 */
0x18, /* 00011000 */
0x00, /* 00000000 */
0x00, /* 00000000 */
```

Characters are rendered by the FBcon driver in [drivers/video/console/newport_con.c `putc`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/video/console/newport_con.c#L371).

Older X11 terminals like `xterm` will use X11 core fonts, stored as [PCF bitmap fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Compiled_Format) or (later) [PostScript fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts), these days usually found in `/usr/share/fonts/X11`. Characters are rendered by the X11 server.

Modern X11 terminals like `gnome-terminal` and `konsole` will use XFT fonts, stored in TrueType or OpenType format in `/usr/share/fonts`. They're rendered by the X11 client through the FreeType library.

---

For a low level OS class, changing the VGA font might be a good trick. For a high level IT class, you could edit a TrueType font to show different things and switch between the fonts in a text processor.

PS: WingDings already demonstrates this by e.g. drawing `J` as a smiley face:

[image: Outlook screenshot showing that J turns into a smiley when the font is changed to Wingdings]

Comment: Great answer. Re: WingDings, I'm not sure that is the same. Even if wingdings is accepted as a valid font for representing unicode in a whacky way (which is nonsensical, right?? J != Smiley), if you want to talk about wingdings in a document that uses a standard font, you would need alternate code points to show the wingdings. There is an answer to this online and I'll find it.

Comment: WingDings predates Unicode and renders the ASCII range weirdly. It's not the same as Unicode emoji that uses standardized code points for symbols.

Comment: Cool! So, now some of the wingdings have unicode encodings [you probably already knew this]. http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html. In word 2016 the wingding font is unicode, I think. I copied an "a" out of word and did ord("a") in python, I get the expected (base10) 97. When I copy a smiley face, however, ord(smiley) = 61514.

Comment: Word 2016 inserts smiley faces as Unicode smiles in your current font. Word 1995 would have inserted a capital `J` and set the font of that one letter to Wingdings (sometimes with [funny results](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060523-10/?p=31103)). Microsoft is also aware of the problem: Office will try to auto-translate copy/paste into Unicode to avoid stray "J"s, so copy-pasted data can be misleading. Try it in Notepad or another very dumb non-WordProcessor editor to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Kirill, I found that they were in my font directories. I went to the following locations

`/usr/share/fonts
/usr/local/share/fonts`

The fonts seem to be in some binary format. vi font.ttf just shows a bunch of garbage. Next I

`rm -rf *`

Now all of my programs are mad at me and throw up these error messages, but I can't understand what they're complaining about.

I did this in virtual box, no one faint.

[image]